# Need help updating old JSP code. Object types in tableData tags

Tags: jsf

I am trying to update some old JSF code to run with newer versions of things (JDK 1.8.0_161, Apache Tomcat/8.5.42, javax.faces-2.4.0, javax.servelet.jsp-api-2.3.3)

The dataTable tag is returning the wrong class for the returned data set, String instead of ServerBean.

The specific error is:

`reason=500 - javax.servlet.ServletException:
    /server.jsp(132,9) '#{m.name}'
    Property [name] not found on type [java.lang.String]`

I have researched this for 3 full days and have come up empty.
There is JSF with HTML that displays a table with data from a database.
The issue is that the variable that is returned is supposed to be a java class, but it is coming back as a string.  I have limited experience with JSF/JSP, but will try to include that I think is relevant.

- I have updated all to compile under 1.8
- I have updated DTDs and DOCTYPEs
- I have updated the serious HTML issues as reported by eclipse Java EE plugin
- I have updated the collections in the java
  code to be typed: `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<ServerBean>`
- I have made sure that ServerBean class is on the classpath `<%@ page import="com.xxx.yyy.beans.ServerBean"%>`

**JSP:**

```
<h:dataTable>
   </h4> <h:dataTable id="servers" value="#{serverdefn.serverList}" var="m" styleClass="font1">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputLink value="#{m.name}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{m.name}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

**WEB-INF/server-defn.xml:**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>server1</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.xxx.yyy.beans.ServerBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>name</property-name>
        <value>Local</value>
    </managed-property>
...

</managed-bean>



<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>serverlist</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.ArrayList</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <list-entries>
        <value>#{server1}</value>
        <value>#{server2}</value>
    </list-entries>
</managed-bean>
```

**ServerBean.java:**

```
protected ArrayList<ServerBean> serverList;

public ArrayList<ServerBean> getServerList() {
    return serverList;
}
```

As the previous implementation worked, I believe it would bring the variable **m** as a ServerBean.   The new stuff is bringing it in as a String.

Where/how does one specify the type of the object that is returned?
I was hoping that adding types to the java collections in ServerBean.java would trigger that, but it did not.  I also looked to see if I should do something in the XML, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: JSF2.4 does not exist (bad 'release formality due to oracle being bad). 2.3.x is the latest. JSP has been deprecated since 8 years for use with JSF in favour of facelets. And if you replace `#{m.name}` with `#{m}`, what do you see? And using managed bean this way has not been in use in modern JSF for many years too btw... And the ServerBean.java looks weird too compared to what you have in the xml definition

Comment: That is all good to know.  I know I was working with old tech, wasn't sure if I would have to change stacks.  The #{m}  prints as a java object address.  The collection that is comes from prints as an address and shows that two elements that are contained

Comment: No change switching to 2.3.9

Comment: Although, #{m} is now com.xxx.yyy.beans.ServerBean@1a50788  which is good

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you meant by "And the ServerBean.java looks weird too compared to what you have in the xml definition"

Comment: The ServerBean code has a getServerList() that resturns an ArrayList<ServerBean>... That is illogical. And it might just now be that the managedProperty does not work well in JSF 2.3... (jsf managed beans have been superceeded by cdi ones and also are deprecated)

Comment: So why is it illogical for getServerList() to return an ArrayLIst<ServerBean>?  Maybe if I knew what that should be, I could fix?

Comment: Sorry, since you have `#{serverdefn.serverList}` in your bean I fail to see the relation to the ServerBean...  But maybe there is some prehistoric JSF 1.x stuff in here that I don't remember anymore. Better to switch to CDI annotations imo.